# PHP login function script not working

Tags: php

It looks like I have some problem with this code. I need to pass `$uid` and `$password` to check the user. I thought I had it correct but it's still not working and I can't figure it out. I'm new to programming and your help would be greatly appreciated!

update..

this following function works fine but when I modify it as below, it gives me bunch errors..

```
public function getUser($uid, $password) {
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = '$uid' AND pswd = '$password'") or die(mysql_error());

    $no_of_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
    if ($no_of_rows > 0) {

        $result = mysql_fetch_array($result);
        return $result;    

    } else {

        return false;
    }
}
```

**user_function.php**

```
<?php

class DB_Functions {

    private $db;

    function __construct() {

        require_once 'db_connect.php';

        $this->db = new DB_Connect();
        $this->db->connect();
    }

    public function getUser($uid, $password) {
        $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id=? AND pswd=?");
        $stmt->execute(array($uid, $password));
        return $stmt->fetch();
    }

}

?>
```

**index.php**

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['tag']) && $_POST['tag'] != '') {

    $tag = $_POST['tag'];

    require_once 'include/db_functions.php';
    $db = new DB_Functions();

    $response = array("tag" => $tag, "success" => 0, "error" => 0);

    if ($tag == 'login') {

        // check for user
        $user = $db->getUser($_POST['id'], $_POST['pswd']);

        if ($user != false) {

            $response["success"] = 1;
            $response["user"]["id"] = $user["id"];

            echo json_encode($response);

        } else {

            $response["error"] = 1;
            $response["error_msg"] = "Incorrect email or password!";
            echo json_encode($response);
        }
```

Comment: Since this is the ***third*** time you're posting this, I have to ask: *What isn't working?*

Comment: In your `getUser` function, is `$db` in scope?

Comment: 1. you don't check for database errors at all. 2. you assume the query succeeded. 3. did you try `var_dump($user)` to see what the query call is giving you?

Comment: @andrewsi looks like you win this round! OP has to use `$this->db`

Comment: @Matt it was a close vote, the comment is automated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think your database connection is in scope; try:

```
public function getUser($uid, $password) {
    $stmt = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id=? AND pswd=?");
    $stmt->execute(array($uid, $password));
    return $stmt->fetch();
}
```

But see the comments about checking return values and error messages to see what the database is actually returning.

Answer (score 3):

In the class, the property $db is not referenced correctly.  Try changing

```
public function getUser($uid, $password) {
    $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id=? AND pswd=?");
    $stmt->execute(array($uid, $password));
    return $stmt->fetch();
}
```

to

```
public function getUser($uid, $password) {
    $stmt = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id=? AND pswd=?");
    $stmt->execute(array($uid, $password));
    return $stmt->fetch();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure how to get your DB connection handle but you probably need to reference your DB from class property that is storing it like this:

```
$this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id=? AND pswd=?");
```